# How to run all the robot files inside current directory

Tags: python, multithreading, robotframework, os.walk

I have robot files inside a directory I need to run all the robot file inside it in sorted order.

Below is my code. is it right code or Can we do multithreading for this

```
import robot
import os
_files = []
for (dirname,dirs,files) in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.robot'):
             _files.append(filename)
print (sorted(_files))
s =  sorted(_files) 

for i in s:
   robot.run(s)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because post  belongs on  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot) it's a parallel executor.

Install pabot:

`pip install -U robotframework-pabot`

Example for usage:

`pabot test_directory`

UPDATE:
Also you can use that command line and execute it from python:

`pabot --argumentfile1 arg1.txt --argumentfile2 arg2.txt`

To build this command line use that code:

```
"""your code here..."""

res = ["pabot"]
i = 0
for filename in s:
    i+=1
    res.append("--argumentfile{} {}".format(i, filename))
exec_line = ' '.join(res)
os.system(exec_line)
```

Comment: Pabot will run tests in an arbitrary order, there is no way to sort them in that case.

Comment: @JoonasKöppä always you can exec this line:
```pabot --argumentfile1 arg1.txt --argumentfile2 arg2.txt```, now I will update answer..

Answer (score 0):

try with [robot packages](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.2.2/autodoc/robot.html)..

```
from robot import run

run('path/to/test1.robot','path/to/test2.robot','path/to/test3.robot')
```